# CSS before selector not working

Tags: html, css

I am creating a hover effect

so I have simple text home and background color is purple

I want to add border before the text but the effect is not showing up

I am using the `::before` for that

following is my code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container::before {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">HOME</div>
```

Comment: You forget to add `content: ''`

Comment: yes, @NenadVracar is correct, add it to `.container::before` declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::before` psuedo-element won't be rendered unless you specify how it should be displayed.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container::before {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: block;
  content: "...";
}

.container {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">HOME</div>
```

… but a border before the text sounds more like a left border:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">HOME</div>
```

Comment: why `content: "...";` and   `display: block;`  is require?

Answer (score 0):

The display: block puts the box before the text; additionally, in order for the ::before selector to generate content: ""; must be added with text inside. I have currently hid the content in order to make the box seem empty.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container::before {
  border: 2px solid black;
  content: ".";
  color: purple;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">HOME</div>
```